# Ruby - kernel_require.rb:54 in 'require': Cannot load such file (from GitHub repository)

Tags: ruby, github, open-source, git-clone

I cloned a GitHub directory because I wanted to help on an open-source project.

The link to the project is listed below, so feel free to try it out for yourself.

https://github.com/tupini07/RubyMan

According to the README, I did the following

```
git clone https://github.com/tupini07/RubyMan
cd projects/RubyMan
ruby main.rb
```

**Edit**

I solved the first issue by running gem install win32console, but I still run into the same problem.

**Error Message**

```
C:\Users\darkmouse\Documents\Projects\RubyMan>ruby main.rb
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- 2.0/Console_ext (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/
lib/Win32/Console.rb:12:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/
lib/Win32/Console.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/
lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/
lib/win32console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from C:/Users/darkmouse/Documents/Projects/RubyMan/Board.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from main.rb:4:in `require_relative'
from main.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

**Main.rb**

```
3 require_relative 'player'
4 require_relative 'Board'
5 require_relative 'LoadLevel'
```

**Board.rb**

```
2 require 'win32console'
```

The issues are listed above.

I run a Windows 8 Operating System.

I'd prefer not to bombard the repository with issues, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: by stack trace, do you mean the error message?

Comment: Yes. It should show each line/method call where something went wrong.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with require-relative. I have posted the full trace

Comment: It looks like you need the [`win32console`](http://rubygems.org/gems/win32console) gem.

Comment: Well that seems to solve one problem, but now I ran into a different one. I will have to edit my post

Answer (score 3):

I forked this same GitHub project, RubyMan, and cloned it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed the current stable release of Ruby 2.2.2. I ran into almost the same problem as above when I changed to the RubyMan folder and ran:

```
ruby Main.rb
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- colorize (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/ashok/RubyMan/Board.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from Main.rb:3:in `require_relative'
    from Main.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
    from Main.rb:3:in `each'
    from Main.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Others who ran into a similar problem suggested on GitHub to:

```
sudo gem install colorize
```

Result:

```
Successfully installed colorize-0.7.7
```

Unfortunately, the above problem didn't go away :( I tried many other suggestions. No luck.

However, these two steps resolved the problem:
Step 1:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Result:

```
RubyGems system software updated
```

I understand that this updates all installed gems to their latest versions.

Step 2:

```
sudo gem install colorize
```

Result:

```
Successfully installed colorize-0.7.7
```

Now I am able to launch the RubyMan program by running:

```
ruby Main.rb
```

Result:

```
What size will the board be?
```

And when I enter a number, it displays the 2D RubyMan game ready to play!